# How to redirect a banned user into a certain page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs and I'm trying to make A redirecting function for users who are banned or blocked on the DB/session.

I tried this

> **redirect.js** where the custom redirect function is.

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"

export async function userBanned(context, callback){
    const session = await getSession(context)
    if(session){
        if(session.user?.banned === true){
            // Redirect
            return{
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/blocked',
                    permanent: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return callback(session)
}
```

> And then I used it in the **_app.js** file.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  return userBanned(context, (session) => {
      return{
          props: {
              session,
          }
      }
  })
}
```

What I'm looking to do is basically when the user joins any page in my App and he's banned he then has to get redirected to the /blocked route.

Note: This code doesn't work or give me any logs idk why, But my DB is working and the banned prop is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never called `callback` function here:

```
export async function userBanned(context, callback){
    const session = await getSession(context)
    if(session){
        if(session.user?.banned === true){
            // Redirect
            return{
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/blocked',
                    permanent: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But you dont need to implement `callback` here

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const session = await getSession({ req: context.req })
    if(session){
        if(session.user?.banned === true){
            // Redirect
            return{
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/blocked',
                    permanent: false
                }
            }
        }

    return{
          props: {
              session,
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either, I had returned the Callback in the code above, but for some reason it got cut I just noticed it, sorry about that.

Comment: @viper i jsut realized `getSession` accepts req. check the answer

Comment: Yes, you can pass it as context or req it doesn't make a different getSession will destructor its value.

Comment: can you `console.log(session)` to see if the session exists and then `console.log(session.user?.banned)`. looks like if statements did not get executed

Comment: I console log session from userBanned but it doesn't show anything, But then when I console log from another function that's not in the ** _app.js ** it shows. 
Kinda weird, I think we can't use getServerSideProps in **_app.js** lol
I have to figure out another way to implement the blocking now.

Comment: yes it does not. I just realized you are on _app. you have to add logic for all getServerSideProps or write a middleware

Comment: True yea I have to use middleware for that, Also it's not just the getServerSideProps 

It's the session itself I forgot we have to wrap it with <SessionProvider  /> 
But it can't be done if you used it in **_app.js**.